# How to set the default LibreSSL on Mac to the one installed by homebrew

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew, libressl

I checked the version of LibreSSL on my mac, it's not the latest one.

```
$ openssl version
LibreSSL 2.6.5
```

And I installed a more recent version by homebrew

```
homebrew install libressl
```

The one installed by homebrew is `2.8.3`. But after I installed the new one and typed in the terminal `openssl version`, it still showed `LibreSSL 2.6.5`, which means the new one had not been set as the default.

I know that homebrew has a different installation path. But I don't know how to set the path as the default path for the LibreSSL. How to set the latest version of LibreSSL as the default one in Mac? Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 16):

If you want the Homebrew version of LibreSSL as the default, you have to put it first in the `PATH` environment variable. If you type:

```
brew info libressl
```

You will obtain the command needed to do that:

```
If you need to have libressl first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libressl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```