# Set Openssl 1.1.1 as a default version

Tags: macos, openssl

I have macOS BigSur 11.6. When I run `openssl version` I get

```
LibreSSL 2.8.3
```

What I want is to get this output:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
```

In the `/usr/local/opt/` there are folders: `openssl`, `openssl@3`, `openssl@1.1`.

I ran these commands:

```sh
brew install openssl
brew reinstall openssl@3
sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1 /usr/local/opt/openssl
```

I placed the line `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"` in files `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/bashrc`.

But nothing helps. How can I make the default openssl version 1.1?

Plese, don't offer commands as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62195898/openssl-still-pointing-to-libressl-2-8-3) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056866/how-to-set-the-default-libressl-on-mac-to-the-one-installed-by-homebrew) questions. These commands don't change anything: as soon as I open a new session I get the same LibreSSL 2.8.3 instead of opessl 1.1.1l

```sh
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
source ~/.profile
source ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bashrc
```

**UPD 1**

- `type -a openssl` shows:

```
openssl is /usr/bin/openssl
```

- `echo $PATH` shows:

```
/usr/local/opt/libressl/bin:/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

**UPD 2**

Just made `unset PATH`, set in files `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/bashrc` the same line `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"` and ran this line in bash. Anyway there is the same output for `openssl version`: `LibreSSL 2.8.3`.

- this `bash --norc -c 'PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin; set -x; source ~/.bash_profile'` shows:

```
+ source /Users/sgalich/.bash_profile
++ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
++ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
++ export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib
++ LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib
++ export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include
++ CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include
++ export CPATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include
++ CPATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include
++ export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib
++ LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib
++ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib
++ DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib
++ export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib
++ DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib
```

Comment: What shell are you using, bash or zsh (or something else)? Running `ps $$` should show you what it is.

Comment: hey @GordonDavisson, I'm using bash

Comment: Then I'd expect it to work. What do `type -a openssl` and `echo "$PATH"` show?

Comment: @GordonDavisson, added UPD 1 with the outputs.

Comment: So `/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin` is *not* in your `PATH`; the question is, why not? You put a command to add it in ~/.bash_profile (which is the one that gets run for initial interactive bash shells). Check your ~/.bash_profile to see if there's anything that would exit it before it hits the `PATH=...` command you added, or anything that'd remove/replace it in the `PATH` after that. It may help to get an execution trace with `bash --norc -c 'PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin; set -x; source ~/.bash_profile'` and look for lines like `+ PATH=something`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, updated the question with the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237971/discussion-between-gordon-davisson-and-sgalich).

Comment: having the same issue in macm1 oct.15,2022

Answer (score 3):

On MacOS Monterey (with M1 chip) the paths differed.

I added the following to ~/.zshrc

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was in my `PATH` variable. My problem was solved after adding this line in the `~/.bash_profile`:

```
PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
```

Thanks [@Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) for the answer!